# Rest Template response body is 404 but Status as 500

Tags: java, rest, exception, resttemplate, http-status-codes

I have written a Rest template to call another Rest service Get by id Method.

When i hit URL localhost:8080/v1/{UUID} with invalid Id.

```
public void test(UUID someId) {
    restTemplate.getForObject("localhost:8080/v1/"+id, String.class);
}
```

I am getting body as 404 but Status as 500 Internal Server Error.

I am not sure to handle exception inside method and throw Resource not found exception. Because response is getting from another service[valid 404 for invalid id].

In my service it is 500 because of Null response from above URL.

Could anyone please suggest best practice to handle validations or exceptions in Rest template.

Comment: Well, the javadoc of getForObject() shows that it throws a RestClientException. And the javadoc of RestClientException shows that it has a subclass RestClientResponseException. And the javadoc of that class shows that it gives access to the status code of the response which caused the exception to be thrown.

Comment: Thanks for comment so it is ok to write .getForObject method without exceptions hence it throws RestClientException.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry for that .I called service xyz via Rest template.
Service xyz is throwing 404 hence Resource is not found.
But my service is throwing 500 because response from Service xyz is null.

Question is should i catch exception for restTemplate.getForObject("")  because  already i am getting response from service xyz?? 
}

Comment: If you don't  want it to be thrown and transformed into an error 500, yes. If you don't care about having an erorr 500, no.